# ASP.NET page methods vs web service

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, web-services, pagemethods

I am building a dynamic partial load asp.net page, I would like to use jQuery to call page methods or web service to retrieve the content HTML.

page methods or web service, performance wise, which way is better?

If I call page method, on the server side, does the page go through full lifecycle?

Is there any good resources help me to better understand page method?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can call PageMethods and Web Services without needing a `ScriptManager` control (which generates the JavaScript proxy objects that allow you to use familiar syntax to call web services and page methods).

Article on [using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Article on [using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

Here's an [MSDN article from 2007 on Web Services and Page Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163480.aspx). Looking briefly through it, it seems to still be relevant to how they work / what you need to do to get them to work today.

Performance wise:

> You might expect page methods to offer
>   better performance than Web services.
>   After all, to resolve Web service
>   calls, the ASP.NET runtime has to
>   parse SOAP packets. This, however,
>   isn't exactly true. ASP.NET AJAX
>   installs a tailor-made HTTP handler
>   (see Figure 3) that intercepts all
>   ASMX requests. Requests with a /js
>   suffix are processed differently,
>   working directly with the JSON payload
>   and Web service method. As a result,
>   no SOAP is involved whatsoever and the
>   body of the request simply contains
>   the JSON stream of input arguments.
>   For non-AJAX requests, the new HTTP
>   handler just delegates the call back
>   to the original ASP.NET handler that
>   understands SOAP.

In response to the Page Lifecycle, Page Methods do **not** go through the server-side Page LifeCycle (there is also a [client-side Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb386417.aspx) too).

Comment: hey @Russ same article again!

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - I wasn't expecting it to come up again so soon!

Comment: @RussCam a follow-up question, Are PageMethods Async, or can they be made Async? I have hit a wall where one PageMethods call (that takes about 4 secondsto return) blocks and prevents other timer-based Page method calls from running as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good resource for you :

http://tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-forms---calling-web-service-page-methods-using-jquery

This blog post will walk you through.